# php calling bash problem

Tags: php, bash, cgi

I have this simple php script

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

// Outputs all the result of shellcommand "ls", and returns
// the last output line into $last_line. Stores the return value
// of the shell command in $retval.
$last_line = $output = system ("~/public_html/cgi-bin/srch.sh &> ~/public_html/errors.txt",$retval);

// Printing additional info
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
?>
```

Which relies on srch.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in ~/mail/home/user/mail/domain.com/josh/cur/*
do
grep -i Value $i . &> ~/public_html/yesno.txt;
done
```

However, all that is display in the b rowser is Retval 1, and no error gets recorded to either of the textfiles. Have I mixed stderr and stdout incorrectly, or missed something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$last_line = $output = system ("~/public_html/cgi-bin/srch.sh &> ~/public_html/errors.txt",$retval);`

The above line runs srch.sh and **redirects *all* the output** it produces to errors.txt. Therefore, there is no output left to assign to $output (and $last_line). You'll find your last line (together with the rest of the output) in errors.txt.

If not, try running the shell script directly and see if it produces any output at all.

Comment: I am on a shared server without shell access, and must run by uploading and through a browser, so I can not run it directly. Absolutely nothing is stored in errors.txt